# Name that pattern: whole page pagination (one news article scrolling directly into another article)

Tags: navigation, pagination

As of writing, I'm seeing many online publishers adopting a pattern of vertically scrolling from one page of content (say a news article) directly into the another; the URL updates when the user reaches a certain point on the next page in sequence too and other elements such as ads reload etc.

If you are familiar with this pattern, what are you referring to it as? I have heard various descriptions for it such as infinite pagination and scroll pagination though these terms are often used to describe or conflate other patterns and navigation techniques.

Some examples:

Wired: http://www.wired.co.uk/article/apple-iphone-7-pre-order

The Daily Beast: http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2016/09/08/designer-tom-ford-takes-the-digital-fast-lane-with-a-collection-instantly-available-online.html

Bloomberg: http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-09-09/eu-projects-commitment-to-strengthen-european-ties-after-brexit

Comment: I'd guess it's covered by the "infinite scrolling" pattern seen commonly on search pages.  Maybe "infinite article scrolling", but that's all speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I have always known this as **AJAX pagination**, and it's quite old, only that instead of vertical, it used to be horizontal. You'll find this in all those sites with ridiculous lists made to display advertisements. And if you check closely, you'll see they change the URLs and ads.

While you could argue it could be named *infinite scroll*, the difference is that with infinite scroll you load elements inside the same page. As such, these elements exists only on the context of its container, and you need to visit the page and scroll down to discover them. In the meanwhile with this kind of pagination, pages exists individually and you can access them as such, via a hyperlink or a navigation element.

Simply put: when you reach the bottom of the page, it just clicks the "**next article**" link for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You described infinite scrolling sites.

When this functionality is implemented well, the user can just scroll the list and the articles simply appear as the user scrolls down the page.